# I can't find rails version on the server that host a rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

First of all, I am newbie to rails. i have a website that is written in rails this website is hosted on Ubuntu 14.04 server.when i write `rails -v` it gives   me.

`The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: apt-get install <selected package>`

However, this website is running on this server, so how can i check the rails version on it?

Comment: How did you install rails on ubuntu? Did you install it as service?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the person who has configured the server and deployed the website. so i am digging to know what the rails version and how this website is running.

Comment: How do you know its working? Did you check http://localhost:3000

Comment: the website is published on (Nginix+Phusion Passenger), and the people is using it.

Comment: ohh, I thought you were checking on your local.

Comment: I am not sure why is it happening. Just a suggestions. Check if you have used RVM to install ruby. If yes then maybe try adding this line in your bashrc file. [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory of the Rails application and run `bin/rails -v`. I believe that is the binary the server is using and not a global (or user-specific) one (which seems to not be installed).

Comment: The project hasn't "bin" sub-directory, but it has folder 'script' which has file is called rails , this file content is 
`#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'`

Comment: Does your Gemfile specify the version of Rails?

Comment: yes, Gemfile specify the version of rails `gem 'rails', '3.0.20'` but still i can't raun `rails -v`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that one was sent a bit prematurely. What I was saying: If the Rails version is specified in the Gemfile, I would believe that it is the version actually being run. (this reads on the Passanger documentation)

Comment: I know but when i execute  the command `rails -v` it gives me rails isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

go to your app folder where your model, view and controllers are found and run

```
bundle show rails
```

Comment: would be great if you could specify usage of bundle show rails

Comment: `bundle show rails` will show the source location of rails gem in the bundle and the version installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed on system level but as a gem for your application. Go to your application directory and then check you will get the rails version for your project.

Comment: I go to the root directory of the website and wrote `rails -v` it gives me the same message.

Comment: Add environment with it. Like RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails -v

Comment: Please clarify, I don't understand.

Comment: Have you checked with the previous command I written in my previous comment ?

Comment: I don't want to write a command i don't know what it will produce cause i am on online website.. What this command means and does it has side effects ?

Comment: Man its just will tell you the rails version your app is running. bundle exec is a Bundler command to execute a script in the context of the current bundle (the one from your directory's Gemfile) and RAILS_ENV=production means to run the command for production environment. Just run the command it will not stop your production server :)

Comment: I have ran it, it gives me `Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources`

Comment: Open the gemfile and see what version of ruby its running and run rvm current or ruby -v in your app directory.

Comment: `ruby -v` produces `ruby 1.9.3p545`

Comment: in your project dir or at root ?

Comment: Both give me the same result

Comment: have you installed ruby through rvm? If yes then paste me the output of rvm current

Comment: Unfortunately I am not the man who deployed the website.. I didn't find the rvm installed.... rvm command not found

Comment: Sorry when i write `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails -v` produces  `bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with bundle install`
`

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production rails -v just write this

Comment: it gives `The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: apt-get install <selected package>`